# Two lists sort according to the ordering of one of the lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
       d = {'Dartmouth': 'Peter Smith',  
            'Harvard': 'Karen Samuels',  
            'Stanford': 'Sam Peters',  
            'UCLA': 'Frank Holland',  
            'Brown': 'Michelle Lee}
```

And suppose I have a function called `orderList(list)` that takes in a list of students names and sorts it (doesn't matter how its sorted).

If I create a list out of the values of the dictionary and pass it in into orderList, i.e.

`orderList(['Peter Smith', 'Karen Samuels', 'Sam Peters', 'Frank Holland', 'Michelle Lee']`)

it returns:

```
['Karen Samuels', 'Sam Peters', 'Michelle Lee', 'Peter Smith', 'Frank Holland']
```

How do I get the corresponding keys in my dictionary to also be in the same order as what was outputted from orderList? i.e. if I were to take my keys and put it in a list it should look like:

```
['Harvard', 'Stanford', 'Brown', 'Dartmouth', 'UCLA']
```

So for instance, Harvard should go first because Karen Samuels is first in the returned list and Karen Samuels maps to Harvard in the dictionary.

Comment: do a simple loop that matches and pushes to a univ lst in order?

Comment: Dicts are unordered so you will need and OrderedDict if you want some order maintianed, are the items in the list always in the dict values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you basically want to "invert" the key-value pairs in the dictionary?
This is fairly easy:

```python
new_dict = {v:k for k, v in old_dict.items()}
```

`output = {(expression 1):(expression 2) for (expression 3) in (expression 4)}` is a dict comprehension; and is equivalent to

```python
output = {}
for (expression 3) in (expression 4):
    output[(expression 1)] = (expression 2)
```

and then just use it:

```python
inverted_dictionary = {v:k for k, v in original_dictionary.items()}

out = [inverted_dictionary[i] for i in orderList(original_list))
```

This is a list comprehension, and works similarly to the dict comprehension:

`output = [(expression 1) for (expression 2) in (expression 3)` will get

```python
output = []
for (expression 2) in (expression 3):
    output.append((expression1))
```

(Although (expression 3) in the dict comprehension and (expression 2) in the list comprehension are valid expressions, not all valid expressions will yield valid results in this place. (expression 3) has to be a tuple of names (`",".join(names)`); with whitespaces added around the comma if needed)

Comment: I see, where does `li` come from?

Comment: `li` is the ordered list. I'll change it to `orderList(original_list)`.

Comment: On python 3 `map` is a generator; `[new_dict[x] for x in li]` will work on 2 and 3.

Comment: @Neapolitan Yes, this is true. I think I'll update the answer, because this is the faster and (as far as I am concerned) the more elegant solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an inverse lookup table, then do a lookup on the keys for each value in the new order:

```
>>> d = {'Dartmouth': 'Peter Smith',  
            'Harvard': 'Karen Samuels',  
            'Stanford': 'Sam Peters',  
            'UCLA': 'Frank Holland',  
            'Brown': 'Michelle Lee'}
>>> dinv = {v: k for k,v in d.items()}
>>> order = ['Karen Samuels', 'Sam Peters', 'Michelle Lee', 'Peter Smith', 'Frank Holland']
>>> [dinv[v] for v in order]
```

Output:

```
['Harvard', 'Stanford', 'Brown', 'Dartmouth', 'UCLA']
```

You want to create the lookup table ahead of time as we have done here (O(n) extra memory and O(n) time) rather than scanning the key:value pairs for each value (O(n^2) time).